# Error in production build with Webpack, Babel and React - Error: Cannot find module '@babel/runtime/core-js/get-iterator'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, webpack-cli

I'm creating react application using Babel-7, Webpack. When I try to build an application in production mode following error occurred.

```
/home/mr3/projects/my-project/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:231
                                throw err;
                                ^

Error: Cannot find module '@babel/runtime/core-js/get-iterator'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:470:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
    at require (/home/mr3/projects/my-project/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mr3/projects/my-project/node_modules/preload-webpack-plugin/build/index.js:5:44)
    at Module._compile (/home/mr3/projects/my-project/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
    at require (/home/mr3/projects/my-project/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mr3/projects/my-project/config/webpack/webpack.prod.config.js:5:30)
    at Module._compile (/home/mr3/projects/my-project/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
    at require (/home/mr3/projects/my-project/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/home/mr3/projects/my-project/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:115:13)
    at requireConfig (/home/mr3/projects/my-project/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:117:6)
    at /home/mr3/projects/my-project/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:124:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/home/mr3/projects/my-project/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:122:15)
    at yargs.parse (/home/mr3/projects/my-project/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:228:39)
    at Object.parse (/home/mr3/projects/my-project/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:567:18)
    at /home/mr3/projects/my-project/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:206:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mr3/projects/my-project/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:505:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
```

I've tried to resolve this by adding the latest versions of Babel and Webpack. Removed `node_modules` and re-installed. The issue still exists.

How can I get this error resolved?

Following are the dependencies in my package.json file.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.5.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
    "redux": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node-babel-7": "^2.0.7",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "^3.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.4.24",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "camelcase": "^5.0.0",
    "chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.2",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^5.0.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "exports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "offline-plugin": "^5.0.5",
    "preload-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.22.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5",
    "webpack-auto-inject-version": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.1",
    "webpack-chunk-hash": "^0.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.1.3",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.22.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your stack trace it appears as though you're missing the `@babel/runtime` node module necessary to build your `React` project:

> Error: Cannot find module '@babel/runtime/core-js/get-iterator'

Taking a quick peek at your `package.json` I don't see it listed there as a `dev-dependency`. Maybe you could try installing this library and rebuilding your production build and seeing if this error goes away.

```
npm install @babel/runtime --save-dev
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I've tried with ```@babel/runtime``` and updated the above package.json. I'm still getting the above error.

Comment: I'm using babel 7 with @babel/runtime v 7.2.0  Could you try downgrading to this version and checking if it would work? (don't forget to delete your node_modules and lock files, before reinstalling everything again).